# How to stop mongodb server on startup in Mac?

Tags: mongodb

I recently installed MongoDB Community Edition on macOS.  The manual says to use `brew services start mongodb-community@4.0` to start the server.

When I want to shutdown the server, I enter mongo shell and type `use admin` and then type `db.shutdownServer()`.  But when I reboot the computer, the server is auto started.  How do I prevent it from auto starting at reboot in MacOS?

Comment: Hi LED Fantom any updates?

Answer (score 2):

Your computer can have multiple `LaunchAgents` folders.

My `homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` file was under:

```
/Users/YOUR-USERNAME/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

Deleting it should solve this issue. After that a manual start is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent mongo from autoload on Mac just delete or move this file: `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`

Source: https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/9630872